# Unicode String Killed by TextBox Visual C# (not the display, the actual string)

Tags: c#, unicode, textbox

I have an application that requires the display of unicode strings using a specific lookup-table-esque font.

This font has actual symbols for characters U+0000 to U+0020.

I have no problems building my string from a set of chars. The problem is when I try to set this string to the textbox.

Regardless of the font I choose for the textbox (the special font, or otherwise), when I do "TextBox1.Text = mycrazystring", then check the Text property of TextBox1 (which I just set), I get "", nothing.

Is this because unicode characters U+0000 to U+0020 are unsupported? 
Do they access functions like newline, tab, or backspace, like I suspect they do when they get placed in the text box?

If I build a string containing characters 0000 through 0023 I expect to see at least an exclamation mark in the TextBox1.Text property after the string is assigned to it, but no dice.

Do I need to make a custom font that shifts my current font by 0020?

Comment: Have you tried the same string in a richtextbox?

Comment: For normal Windows text boxes, U+0000 signifies the end of the string. Try replacing it with something else, e.g. U+2400 (␀).

Comment: Is that what the null character is for? Well that certainly explains things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping Unicode characters to unrelated glyphs shouldn't be done. You can end up with lots of problems with text-layout algorithms doing inappropriate things. Mapping the *control characters* to custom glyphs is crazy; it will certainly confuse UI widgets and many other tools.

> Do I need to make a custom font that shifts my current font by 0020?

No, you need to shift it by +E000 or more, into the [Private Use Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Private_use_characters).

Comment: Or use U+2400 through U+2420 (http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf) which are specifically intended to be used as the symbols for control characters.

Comment: Private use area it is! That sorted things out. Those control characters were certainly running amok.